# How Bluetooth works

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can someone explain to me how Bluetooth actually works when connecting an Android device to another one.

Here is what I think I know.

I have two devices.

One will be a client and the other the server, depending which initiates the connection.
The Android device will do a search for devices in Discoverable Mode.
The Android device can list previously paired devices.

A `BluetoothSocket` is opened to create the connection between the devices.
Data can now be transfered
Socket can be closed when completed

Question : if a device shows that there is a connection with a LED, should that LED flicker once the `BluetoothSocket.connect()` is called.

Is there anywhere I can find literature on how it works ect..

The reason for this question is due to my earlier post :

[Android Bluetooth Connecting Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953760/android-bluetooth-connecting-error)

I'm not sure If i am actually connected or not. The Android documentation says there is a boolean called BluetoothSocket.isConnected() but I dont seem to be able to find it. so I cant figure out if I am actually connected or not, and I dont know after "being connected" if I can just start sending data.

Comment: Try http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Tech-Info.aspx ?

Comment: Change is necessary for android 2.1 and 2.2 devices. Don't exactly know why but if you don't do it it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link for `BluetoothSocket.isConnected()` is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#isConnected()). The documentation says `Since API level 14`, which means you need to update your sdk to r14 in order to use the method.

**EDIT:** This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544042/how-to-detect-if-bluetooth-device-is-connected) may help you to find out if you're connected to another bluetooth device

Comment: Ya the Dev pages say its there, but in eclipse it isnt.

Comment: thanks man, figured it was something silly like that. Also I found out how to connect correctly, had to substitute a line of code.


  `tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);`

  with:

  `Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});`
  `tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);`

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you! Happy coding! =)

Comment: Not sure why that change worked, but it did. Any explanation will be great.